# Mapping a single function is slower than twice mapping two separate functions?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, iteration, nested-function

The following example seems to imply run time optimisation that I do not understand

**Can anyone explain this behavior and how it may apply to more generic cases?**

## Example

Consider the following simple (example) functions

```
def y(x): # str output
    y = 1 if x else 0
    return str(y)

def _y(x): # no str
    y = 1 if x else 0
    return y
```

Assume I want to apply the function `y` upon all elements in a list

```
l = range(1000) # test input data
```

## Result

A `map` operation will have to iterate through all elements in the list. It seems counter intuitive that breaking the function apart into a double `map` significantly outperforms the single `map` function

```
%timeit map(str, map(_y, l))
1000 loops, best of 3: 206 µs per loop

%timeit map(y, l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop
```

More generically, this also applies to non standard library nested functions for example

```
def f(x):
    return _y(_y(x))

%timeit map(_y, map(_y, l))
1000 loops, best of 3: 235 µs per loop
%timeit map(f, l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 294 µs per loop
```

Is this a python overhead issue where `map` is compiling the low level python code where possible and consequently being throttled when it has to interpret a nested function?

Comment: I just ran your examples on my machine with python 3.6. On both benchmarks the single map needs only about half as much time per loop compared to the double map. Which python version did you use? My timeit output took about 300 ns per loop, which is much, much faster than your version. Do you have a machine with restricted cpu / ram?

Comment: We ran on a few machines and got the same result using Python 2.7. On Python 3 I think map evaluated in a different way? Also no restrictions on RAM or CPU

Comment: The `map` function in python 2 returns a list. In python 3, it yields the results instead, so they are evaluated on the fly. This explains the different benchmark results.

Comment: @pschill: creating a `map()` iterator object in Python 3 is indeed very fast, but doesn't do any iteration. In Python 2, `map()` does the iteration immediately and returns a list. Add `list()` calls around the `map()` calls if you want to test this in Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `map()` is implemented in C code, and calling to other C-implemented functions is *cheap*, while calling to Python code is expensive. On top of that, calling out to other callables from Python code is expensive too:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f(1)', 'def f(x): return str(x)')
0.21682000160217285
>>> timeit.timeit('str(1)')
0.140916109085083
```

and thirdly, you are passing in the function objects to `map()` (so no further lookups are done), but `y()` has to look up the `str` name each and every time. Global lookups are relatively expensive compared to local lookups; binding a global to a function argument to make it a local can help offset this a little:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f(1)', 'def f(x, _str=str): return _str(x)')
0.19425392150878906
```

Much closer to the `str(1)` version, even though that had to use a *global* too; it can still beat the function call hands-down if you gave the time test a local too:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('_str(1)', '_str = str')
0.10266494750976562
```

So, Python bytecode execution requires an additional object, a stack frame, to be created for each call. That stack frame object has to be managed on a dedicated Python call stack when calling out to other code. Moreover, your `y` function looks up the `str` name as a global each time, whereas the `map(str, ...)` call keeps a single reference to that object and uses it over and over again.

By moving the `str()` call out of the `y` function and letting `map()` call `str()` directly instead through the single reference, you removed the stack handling and global name lookups, and sped things up marginally.

As a diagram, `map(y, l)` executes, per input value:

- Create stackframe for `y`, execute the body

  - look up `str` as a global

    - push `y` stackframe onto stack
    - execute `str(...)`
    - pop stackframe from stack
  - return result

whereas `map(str, map(_y, l))` executes

- Create stackframe for `_y`

  - return result
- execute `str(...)`

The same applies to your `f()` function setup:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return _y(_y(x))
...
>>> timeit.timeit("map(_y, map(_y, l))", 'from __main__ import _y, testdata as l', number=10000)
2.691640853881836
>>> timeit.timeit("map(f, l)", 'from __main__ import f, testdata as l', number=10000)
3.104063034057617
```

Calling `map()` on `_y` twice is faster than nesting the `_y(_y(x))` call in another function, which then has to do global name look-ups and stress the Python stack some more; in your `f()` example each `map()` iteration has to create 3 stack frames and push and pop these on and off the stack, while in your `map(_y, map(_y, ...))` setup, only 2 frames are created per iterated item:

- Create stackframe for `f`, execute the body

  - look up `_y` as a global

    - push `f` stackframe onto stack
    - Create stackframe for `_y`, execute the body
    - pop stackframe from stack
  - look up `_y` as a global  (yes, again)

    - push `f` stackframe onto stack
    - Create stackframe for `_y`, execute the body
    - pop stackframe from stack
  - return result

versus:

- Create stackframe for `_y`, execute the body

  - return result
- Create stackframe for `_y`, execute the body

  - return result

Again, using locals can off-set the difference a little:

```
>>> def f(x, _y=_y):
...     return _y(_y(x))
...
>>> timeit.timeit("map(f, l)", 'from __main__ import f, testdata as l', number=10000)
2.981696128845215
```

but that extra Python frame object is still hobbling the single `map(f, ...)` call.

---

**TLDR**: Your `y()` function suffers from O(N) additional global name lookups and O(N) additional stack frame objects being pushed onto and off the Python stack, compared to the double `map()` version.

If speed matters this match, try to avoid creating Python stack frames and global name lookups in a tight loop.

Comment: Is there an order of operation logic e.g. `is this C func? => No => grab python function` ? Does this also apply for `C` code wrapped into python with e.g. `cython`? With respect to my first question, do all python  functions have to be read from the python `globals()` `dict`?

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane: Name lookups in the global namespace don't distinguish between implementation details, it's just a name -> object mapping. Cython is another means of defining native objects, no different from the native objects defined in C code.